# Failed to communicate a dockerized process with elastic search with "None of the configured nodes are available"

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, spring-boot

I have spring boot application which communicate with ElasticSearch 5.0.0 alpha 2.
My application successfully communicate with elastic and preform several queries.

When I try to dockerize my application, it fails to communicate with ElasticSearch, and I get the following error:

**None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]**

I have spent a lot of time on the internet, but I have found problems when the ElasticSearch is dockerized, but in my case, the client is dockerized, and it is working fine without the docker.

The command I used to create the docker image is: **docker build -t my-service .**

The DockerFile is:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD ./build/libs/myjarfile-2.0.0.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8090
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

To execute the image i use: **docker run --name myname -d -p 8090:8090 -t my-service**

Can someone share his/her experience with this issue?

Thanks
Guy Hudara

Comment: Can you give some more information like what OS are you using, how you configure ES in you app etc?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your elasticsearch is not available on your dockerized host. When you put something in a docker container it also gets isolated on a network layer and localhost is localhost of the docker container but **not** the host itself. Therefore if you have elasticsearch also in a docker container use container linking and environment variable injection or reference your host machines address of your main network interface – **not** loopback – to your app.

**Option 1**

assuming that elasticsearch exposes 9200 try to run the following

```
$ docker run -d --name=elasticsearch elasticsearch
$ docker run -d --name=my-app --link elasticsearch:elasticsearch -p 8090:8090 my-app
```

Then you can define elasticsearch address in your app using env variable `${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_9200_TCP_ADDR}`.

**Option 2**

assuming your host machine runs on 192.168.1.10 you can also do the following:

```
$ docker run -d -p 9200:9200 elasticsearch
$ docker run -d -p 8090:8090 my-app
```

note that the name for the easticsearch container is optional here but the exposing of elasticsearch port mandatory. In this case you'll have to configure your elasticsearch host in your app given address of `192.168.1.10`.